# constexpr function that returns address of the templated function instance

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

Consider the following example:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct bar
{
    void baz() { std::cout << "bar::baz" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename Signature>
struct function_traits;

template <typename ReturnType, typename Class, typename ...ArgumentTypes>
struct function_traits<ReturnType (Class::*)(ArgumentTypes...)>
{
    typedef ReturnType (Class::*Signature)(ArgumentTypes...);
    typedef ReturnType (*FuncPtr)(void const *ip, ArgumentTypes&& ...);

    template <Signature mf>
    static ReturnType wrapper(void const *p, ArgumentTypes&& ...args)
    {
        Class* instance = const_cast<Class*>(static_cast<Class const *>(p));
        return (instance->*mf)(std::forward<ArgumentTypes>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename Type>
constexpr auto wrap(Type p) -> typename function_traits<Type>::FuncPtr
{
    return &(function_traits<Type>::template wrapper<p>); // ERROR: Address of overloaded function 'wrapper' does not match required type 'void (const void *)'
}

int main()
{
    auto v = wrap(&bar::baz);
}
```

I've tested it with Xcode 4.5.2 - Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Do I want too much?

Comment: Well, the error makes sense. `wrap` is declared to return a function pointer with the same signature as what it's wrapping, but you're returning the wrapper itself (which takes an extra initial `void const*` parameter). How is `v` supposed to be used? Nice use of templates, by the way -- you should see ugliness of my own functors in MSVC2010 (which doesn't support half of the features you're using).

Comment: `wrap` should return the address of the function `wrapper` which type is `void (*)(void const *)` as I hope. `v` is just a function pointer, it could be invoked with the pointer to the `bar` object.

Comment: Interesting. The bug persists even when the parameter pack is removed. Anyway, note that this functionality is already built into `std::function` and (if I recall correctly) `std::tr1::function`. Just construct it from the pointer to member. It even converts implicitly from a nonstatic member pointer. It doesn't use `void*`, obviously; I hope that's not essential to your architecture :vP .

Comment: @arabesc: Ah, ignore my comment, sorry. I misread the definition of `FuncPtr` ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter declaration

```
constexpr auto wrap(Type p)
```

is incompatible with the template-name

```
template wrapper<p>
```

Even in a `constexpr` function, a parameter cannot be used as a constant expression.

Usually this error manifests itself as an attempt to adjust the `constexpr` function's return type according to the value of the argument, but this is a little subtler since the type expression is part of the value computation, with the value always having the same type.

The fundamental problem is that the template is being asked to do runtime work. You can decide what PTMF to call it with at runtime.

`constexpr` never restricts the arguments that may be passed to a function. (I.e., that a function may only be called with constant arguments.) It only makes the function a candidate for use in contexts where a constant is required.

Comment: +1. A workaround would be to pass the function pointer as a template parameter in the first place, i.e. `wrap<&bar::baz>()`.

Comment: @Cameron Alas, you can't do that without first naming the return type, host class, and argument list as preceding template arguments. Maybe `decltype( wrap_helper( &bar::baz ) )::wrapper< &bar::baz >`, and wrap that in a macro. I'll stick to `std::function` for now :)

Comment: … duh, `wrapper< decltype( &bar::baz ), &bar::baz >` and wrap that in a macro. Anyway, it's a last resort.

Comment: Hmm, shame there's no way to do that without a macro even in the latest compilers (that I know about anyway). It does give the advantage that the method pointer never needs to be stored (so, you can convert arbitrarily-sized method pointers to fixed-size data pointers). This means you can safely avoid heap allocation in the functor. Also, there's a chance that the compiler can fully resolve the functor calls at compile time, since the actual function address is known at that time (I implemented a similar functor myself a while back).

Comment: @Potatoswatter, the main idea was to go from macros. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Cameron, you catch the idea :) [here](http://habrahabr.ru/post/166589/) is my implementation with macros, look for the `function.hpp` at the end of the post.